# FFMPEG text file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am giving the input file in the command line like this:

```
ffmpeg -i catch.flv.
```

The information about the file such as resolution, frame rate, bit rate etc is displayed in the terminal. I want this information to be stored as a (.txt) file. I have tried `ffmpeg -i catch.flv > catch.txt`. The .txt file was created successfully but the information is not stored in it. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

`ffmpeg` prints that information to the standard error, not to the standard output; to capture it, you should use e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i catch.flv 2> catch.txt
```

(you can have a look [here](http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html) to learn more about standard streams redirection)